# objective c - Inline condition checking - what is it?

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements

Please forgive the title, it's probably wrong, since I don't know anything about it. Because of that, I didn't have any search terms to look it up, so could someone explain me what does this mean and how to use it? I just picked this example as I recently found it.

```
id item = [arr count] > 0 ? arr[0] : nil;
```

Comment: This is use of a ternary operator, also called conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if.

Comment: @pennstatephil You referenced a C# doc for an Objective C question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the same as

```
id item;
if ([arr count] > 0) {
   item = arr[0];
}else{
   item = nil;
}
```

Comment: Except you probably want to declare `item` *before* the if statement if you want to use it afterwards.

Comment: @MikeD you are right.  I updated the answer.